# Automatically generate sql insert statement with dummy data

Tags: sql, database, insert, dummy-data

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Quickest way to fill SQL Table with Dummy Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899654/quickest-way-to-fill-sql-table-with-dummy-data)

I'm looking for a tool that will generate insert statement for an existing database filled with dummy data.
This is meant to allow testing of the system.

I'm thinking about something that reads the type of each field and generates data accordingly. If the field name is "username" for example, it's best if it actually knows to take common user names. It should obviously also keep database relations with foreign key constraints.

This doesn't seem too difficult to write this. Is there anything ready which I can use?

Thanks, Omri

Answer (score 11):

i use this one
[http://www.generatedata.com/](http://www.generatedata.com/#about) and its free :)

Answer (score 3):

Checkout http://www.generatedata.com/ its a gpl tool to do stuff like that. Most people write scripts that do it because its really hard to account for all the constraints and setup of database tables.

Answer (score 3):

Check out Red Gate's [SQL Data Generator](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Data_Generator/) - not free, but is ready to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like very unique requirement of data generation but this answer might help.

[quickest-way-to-fill-sql-table-with-dummy-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899654/quickest-way-to-fill-sql-table-with-dummy-data)